# How do images in a property of an object work and setting them from bitmap?

Tags: android, image, kotlin, bitmap, int

A little bit of a backstory, I am currently an IOS developer transitioning into working with Android, more specifically Kotlin, and the way that Android Development handles images confuses the hell out of me!

Can someone please explain to me how/why images are saved as type Int and how can I set an image as a property on of my objects. I understand Drawables have Id's that are type Int and that I should save them that way, but I am currently trying to get an image from the user's gallery and the data from the Intent on the "onActivityResult" function comes back as an Intent for which I then convert to a bitmap.

SUMMARY: How do I properly work with Image properties in Kotlin (Int) and convert a bitmap to type Int to set my property?

Comment: "Can someone please explain to me how/why images are saved as type Int" -- they are not saved as type `Int`. A drawable *resource* has a resource identifier that is an `Int` (`R.drawable.whatever`). You are confusing an identifier (resource identifier, database primary key, filesystem path, URL, etc.) with the data obtained from that identifier. "the data from the Intent on the "onActivityResult" function comes back as an Intent for which I then convert to a bitmap" -- that will be a `Bitmap` object, most likely.

Comment: So my object has an image property that is type Int right now and I am using that to save my image. Should i change it to something else? Also, how can I take that bitmap object and save it to my object? Thank you so much!!

Comment: "So my object has an image property that is type Int right now and I am using that to save my image" -- I do not know what "save my image" means in this context. You might consider editing your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating what you are doing and using that to better illustrate the problems that you are encountering.